# Array not being filled when the HTML page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I am working on a project using Google Apps Script coupled with HTML and JS. I am fairly new to programming, so bear with me if this is a simple question.

Basically, in my JS file I have a function that calls a function contained in the Google Apps Script (from now on, GAS) file using [this method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run); the GAS function populates an array with values retrieved from a Google Sheets and returns the array. This array is then used by the JS file to populate a drop down list in the HTML file.

The issue is that the dropdown list is not populated at all; if I reload the page with the Google Chrome console on, I see that the array is empty; however, if I click on the empty array, the values are shown, as if it is not populated on page load. See the picture below to have a better understanding of what I mean:

[Google Chrome Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWeCC.png)

Below you'll find the relevant snippets of code that handle the differente functions:

JS:

```js
$(function() {

  var cities = [];

  function onSuccess(elem, array) {
    var i = 0;
    for (item in elem) {
      array.push(elem[i])
      i++;
    };
    return array
  };

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withUserObject(cities).populate();

  //Create the dropdown menu for the cities

  for (city in cities) {
    var element = $("#city1").append("<option value=" + cities[city].toLowerCase() + ">" + cities[city] + "</option>");
    console.log(city);
  };

  [...]

});
```

HTML:

```html
<select id="city1" name="city" placeholder="City"><option id="citydummy">City</option></select>
```

Google Apps Script:

```js
function populate() {
  var db = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEETID');
  var check = true;
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 2; i < db.getLastRow(); i++) {
    db.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, "1").getValue()
    array.push(db.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, "1").getValue())
  }
  return array;
}
```

Many thanks in advance for anyone who will contribute!

Comment: If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following modification for JS? HTML and GAS are not modified. Data obtained at `populate()` is directly sent to `onSuccess()`, and imported the data to the list.

#### JS :

```
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).populate();
});

function onSuccess(cities) {
  for (city in cities) {
    var element = $("#city1").append("<option value=" + cities[city].toLowerCase() + ">" + cities[city] + "</option>");
    console.log(city);
  };
};
```

If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.